# Using created ALU to make a bigger one

Tags: verilog

I have a 8-bit ALU unit in verilog that can do addition, invert, etc. This single unit is tested and performs correctly. When I combine 4 of these to make a bigger ALU every  output is correct except when I choose the addition operation it comes out as
`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx01010101`, basically the first alu does the work right then the output from the second is `xxxxxxxx` as is the third and fourth. This is really frustrating!!

the 8 bit module( it would be nice to point if this model is behavioral or structural model i  go for the former!)

```
module alu_8bit(
  output reg [7:0] out,
  output reg cout,g,e,
  input [7:0] A,B,
  input cin,
  input [2:0] S

);
    //used functions 
  parameter BUF_A = 3'b000;
  parameter NOT_A = 3'b001;
  parameter ADD = 3'b010;
  parameter OR = 3'b011;
  parameter AND = 3'b100;
  parameter NOT_B = 3'b101;
  parameter BUF_B = 3'b110;
  parameter LOW = 3'b111;

  always @(A or B or S) begin
    //Comparator
    g = A>B;
    e = A==B;

    //Other selective functions
    case(S)
      BUF_A: out = A;
      NOT_A: out = ~A;
      ADD: {cout,out} = A+B+cin;
      OR: out = A | B;
      AND: out = A & B;
      NOT_B: out = ~B;
      BUF_B: out = B;
      LOW: out = {8{1'b0}};
    endcase
  end

endmodule
```

Here is the code of the bigger one:

```
module alu_32bit(
  output [31:0] out,
  output cout,g,e,
  input [31:0] A,B,
  input cin,
  input [2:0] S

);

  wire e1,e2,e3,e4;
  wire g1,g2,g3,g4;


  alu_8bit ALU1(out[7:0],cin2,g1,e1,A[7:0],B[7:0],cin,S);
  alu_8bit ALU2(out[15:8],cin3,g2,e2,A[15:8],B[15:8],cin2,S);
  alu_8bit ALU3(out[23:16],cin4,g3,e3,A[23:16],B[23:16],cin3,S);
  alu_8bit ALU4(out[31:24],cout,g4,e4,A[31:24],B[31:24],cin4,S);

  assign g = g4 | (e4 & g3) |(e4 & e3 & g2) | (e4& e3 & e2 & g1);
  assign e = e4 & e3 & e2 & e1;

endmodule
```

Can any one give some help?! if you need more info just tell me.

Edited:

Waveform pic clearly input comes in correct but output not
[image: Waveform ALU2]

The dataflow diagram shows that ALU1 output is just fine

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the Carry out from ALU1(adder) is not X?

Comment: yes the carry is zero and the inputs to the next one are correct do you want me to put the inpleemntation of the 8 bit?

Comment: The 8 Bit ALU might be useful to see, A screenshot of the waveforms of ALU2 might be useful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sensitivity list for the main part of the ALU doesn't include `cin`.

Comment: lol, it would have taken me forever to realize that... thanks a lot. Could you point out if this module is a structural or a behavioral model?!

Comment: @Doggynub, it would have been much easier with a clocked ALU.

Comment: @Doggynub I would recommend replacing `always @(A or B or S)` with `always @*` and not worry about sensitivity lists again. They are generally for simulation only and ignored by synthesis tools.